# maven mvn eclipse:eclipse does not include webapp dependencies in deployment assembly

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications

I created a webapp java project, with a pom file. then I type "mvn eclipse:eclipse" and import it into eclipse.

(btw, how do you usually directly import a java project into eclipse? I have always found eclipse:eclipse works perfectly, just that I have to do this extra step to type eclipse:eclipse )

then in eclipse, I edit and compile the project, all good.
but when I run the project on a tomcat server in eclipse, it fails to find many basic dependency classes such as javax.servlet etc. The reason is that these dependency jars are not included into the deployment assembly into WEB-APP/lib. I have to manually click "properties"-->"assembly"-->add ...

is there a way to tell mvn eclipse:eclipse to do this automatically?

thanks
Yang

Answer (score 1):

> > how do you usually directly import a java project into eclipse

Installing [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin enables importing Maven projects directly from the Import Project wizard.

> > it fails to find many basic dependency classes such as javax.servlet

This should not happen as long as you include those dependencies in your POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe it works with the m2e natively in eclipse, which would be smart enough to add these dependencies to the deployment. But I tend to not use m2e because some plugins need to run in a "lifecycle that is not supported by eclipse" (this is the error given by eclipse sometimes). "mvn eclipse:eclipse" is the always-working way for me to get a project into eclipse, but only up to the stage of compiling.